# Can't fetch dynamically changed HTML content(by JavaScript) in android using AsyncTask.

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, android-asynctask

I'm using python script to dynamically change the content of my web-page. The link of the web page is: [[HERE]](https://rasppiclient.herokuapp.com/)

The web page contains table which has two columns:
1) Values between 1 to 5.
2) And the time when it is uploaded on the page.

It is displayed dynamically by the JavaScript on the page. See the source of the page opening the link above.

Now I'm creating a android application which displays the values in the text view by fetching that page and parsing the HTML. But the page source only contains JavaScript code. So whenever I fetch the HTML, it only displays the JavaScript even if it contains more than one rows with values.

My question is how to fetch those values dynamically?

I'm using AsyncTask and scheduling it every 10 seconds. My code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView et ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    task.execute(new String[]{"https://rasppiclient.herokuapp.com/"});

callAsynchronousTask();

}



public void callAsynchronousTask() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        DownloadWebPageTask performBackgroundTask = new DownloadWebPageTask();
                        // PerformBackgroundTask this class is the class that extends AsynchTask
                        performBackgroundTask.execute(new String[]{"https://rasppiclient.herokuapp.com/"});
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 10000); //execute in every 50000 ms
}



public class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {


            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}}
```

Comment: This does not work with `DefaultHttpClient`. You have to openthe site so the javascript gets executed and then scrap it.

Comment: How to do this in android? @MuratK.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work with `DefaultHttpClient`. What you could to is the evaluate the javascript and then get the content with [AndroidJSCore](https://github.com/ericwlange/AndroidJSCore).

```
JSContext context = new JSContext();
context.evaluateScript(yourJsString);
context.property("getWhatYouWantHere");
```

An example from the github looks like this

```
JSContext context = new JSContext();
context.evaluateScript("a = 10");
JSValue newAValue = context.property("a");
System.out.println(df.format(newAValue.toNumber())); // 10.0
String script =
  "function factorial(x) { var f = 1; for(; x > 1; x--) f *= x; return f; }\n" +
  "var fact_a = factorial(a);\n";
context.evaluateScript(script);
JSValue fact_a = context.property("fact_a");
System.out.println(df.format(fact_a.toNumber())); // 3628800.0
```

Comment: But I have JavaScript which generates table view for the page. So i've to set whole JavaScript as a string here??

Comment: See the script on the page which I've mentioned

Comment: @14bce109 Yes, but this will not work for ajax. In that case you can use the android `WebView` class for loading and scraping.